# can't find variable: function name in external js file

Tags: javascript, html, function

i have a problem with my website. I have couple of functions in java script that works in `<body> <script> js code </script></body>` but when i link external js file with exactly the same code functions that are called by `onclick"function name"` attribute stop working and I get error can't find variable: function name also it seems like it can't find some of ids for variables because i can't log them. this is my code

```js
function onload() {
  /* leaderboard variable */
  let x = document.getElementById('boardw');
  /* help popup variable*/
  let y = document.getElementById('helpw');
  /* settings popup variable*/
  let z = document.getElementById('setw');
  /* help button variable*/
  let a = document.getElementById('help');
  /* dropdown container variable*/
  let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  /* footer popup display none*/
  document.getElementById('card').style = "display: none;";

  /* variable test */
  console.log(x);

  /* show footer popup */
  function showCard() {
    document.getElementById('card').style = "display: block;";
    document.getElementById('footer').style = "display: none;";
  }
  /* hide footer popup */
  function hide() {
    document.getElementById('card').style = "display: none;";
    document.getElementById('footer').style = "display: block;";
  }

  /* choose time in dropdown function */
  function show(anything) {

    document.getElementById('txt').value = anything;
  }

  /* show options in dropdown */
  dropdown.onclick = function() {
    dropdown.classList.toggle('active');
  }
  /* show leaderboard function*/
  function menu1() {

    x.classList.toggle('active');
  }
  /* show help popup function*/
  function menu2() {

    y.classList.toggle('active');
    a.classList.toggle('active');

  }
  /* show settings function*/
  function menu3() {

    z.classList.toggle('active');
  }

  /* hide popups function*/
  function remove() {
    y.classList.remove('active');
    z.classList.remove('active');
    x.classList.remove('active');
    dropdown.classList.remove('active');

  }
}
```

```html
<body id="bd" style="" onload="onload()">

  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


  <!-- dropdown select time window  -->
  <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown" onclick="">
    <!-- dropdown textbox with chosen informations -->
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="txt" value="" placeholder="     select the test duration" readonly>
    <!-- options for dropdown select -->
    <div class="option">
      <div onclick="show('   1 minute')">1 minute</div>
      <div onclick="show('   2 minutes')">2 minutes</div>
      <div onclick="show('   3 minutes')">3 minutes</div>
      <div onclick="show('   5 minutes')">5 minutes</div>
      <div onclick="show('   10 minutes')">10 minutes</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- checkboxes for charset in game -->
  <div id="charset">
    <!-- normal letters check -->
    <div>
      <label for="cka">a</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cka" class="ck">
    </div>
    <!-- capital letters check -->
    <div>
      <label for="ckB">A</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ckB" class="ck">
    </div>
    <!-- numbers check -->
    <div>
      <label for="ck1">1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ck1" class="ck">
    </div>
    <!-- special characters check -->
    <div>
      <label for="ck>">#</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ck" class="ck">
    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- about popup -->
  <footer onclick="remove()">
    <!-- show popup btn -->
    <button id="footer" onclick="showCard();" style="">i</button>
    <!-- popup container -->
    <div id="card" class="card" style="">
      <!-- close popup btn -->
      <button id="close" onclick="hide()">x</button>
    </div>

  </footer>

  <!-- menu -->
  <menu>
    <!-- leaderboard popup -->
    <button class="menu" id="board" onclick="menu1()">L</button>
    <div id="boardw" style="" class="menuw">
    </div>

    <!-- help popup -->
    <button class="menu" id="help" onclick="menu2()">?</button>
    <div id="helpw" style="" class="menuw">
    </div>

    <!-- settings pop -->
    <button class="menu" id="settings" onclick="menu3()">S</button>
    <div id="setw" style="" class="menuw">
    </div>

  </menu>

  <!-- start game btn -->
  <div id="gma">
    <a href="#"><button id="start">Start</button></a>
  </div>

  <!-- frame for higher resolution screen-->
  <div class="h"> </div>



</body>
```

Comment: Did you check the `network` tab in dev tools to see if the script loads?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes script loads correctly and functions that weren't called by onclick work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped your functions in `function onload() { ... }` so the inner functions can't be reached from HTML.

1. Remove this wrapper.
2. Add `defer` attribute to the script

Answer (score 0):

put functions and variables outside the onload function,
or use addEventListener to call listener
document.getElementById("cka").addEventListener("click", function(){
...
})